# Watch DOM changes with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im having a form that is hidden in the beginning with ng-if so its removed from the DOM

later on i unhide the form and try to submit the btn i have in my form with this

```
<form action="post.php" ng-if="success == true" method="post">

<input ng-model="test" id="openPaymentButton" type="submit" value="test">
</form>


$("#openPaymentButton").click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ng-hide/ng-show inplace of ng-if.
ng-if does not render the element in DOM where as ng-hide/ng-show render the elements in DOM and hide/show based on condition.

```
<form action="post.php" ng-show="success == true" method="post">

<input ng-model="test" id="openPaymentButton" type="submit" value="test">
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is that, the form needs to be removed from the dom so the user cant manipulate with the input fields (have not included that in the questing)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use jQuery for handling clicks. Use Angular.

Try

```
<input ng-model="test" ng-click="foo();" id="openPaymentButton" type="submit" value="test">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick